# Is String.format() on Android supposed to be timezone-aware?

Tags: java, android, timezone, string-formatting

I use the following code to convert the timestamp of a GPS location to a human-readable form:

```
String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS", location.getTime())
```

As per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29), GPS location timestamps should be in UTC. However, the string I get back is in local time (tested on two different devices).

I have tried using the other form of `String.format()`, which takes an additional `Locale` argument, and passing it a null locale (which, as per the docs, means "no localization") – still the same. (And the documentation of `Locale` doesn't mention time zones at all, thus I doubt locales are the issue here.)

My other suspicion was that the GPS stack might not behave as specified, supplying local time instead of UTC. I tested this with

```
String.format("%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS", (long) 0)
```

which returns

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

which is the beginning of the epoch plus the timezone offset for CET (the time zone of the device). Thus the offset is clearly added by `String.format()`.

Is `String.format()` supposed to do any time zone conversion? How can I influence this behavior, i.e. choose which time zone to convert to or suppress conversion altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.format` represent a date/time in default timezone. To format in UTC, use a `SimpleDateFormat` instead, where you can explicitly set timezone which you want to use:

```
String formatInUtc(long millis) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return df.format(new Date(millis));
}
```

E. g.:

```
System.out.println(formatInUtc(0L)); //  1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

By the way, locale and timezone are orthogonal things: locale determines aspects of textual representation (digits, signs, separators, language), while timezone determines how the clock is shifted from UTC.

Answer (score 1):

String.format is not time zone aware.  Use Joda time library. The datetime zone and datetimeformat classes in the library will let you format datetime that will be timezone aware. You will get a lot of examples online on how to do that, so I am not getting into details here. :)

Comment: If `String.format()` were completely unaware of timezones, I'd expect `0L => 1970-01-01 00:00:00`, but apparently there is some limited time zone awareness in that it expects input to be in UTC and formats output as local time – what it missing is a way to influence that processing. I ended up using `DateFormat` as it is readily available and really simple.